AlmaLinux 8 vsftpd as root user
I installed a fresh, AlmaLinux 8.10 in a virtual machine (VirtualBox), i.e. I do not care at all about security.
I used the instructions of the Configure Vsftpd FTP Server on Rocky Linux 8|AlmaLinux 8 guide, skipping section 2. Create the FTP User and User Directory, as I wanted to connect as root. So I followed steps:

Install vsftpd on Rocky Linux 8/ AlmaLinux 8
Configure vsftpd on Rocky Linux 8/ AlmaLinux 8. (Many settings were already set as default)

I added/changed the following settings, compared to the default, i.e. only the differences are listed:
/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
;root

/etc/vsftpd/user_list
#root

/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
# Disable for fail2ban to work!
xferlog_std_format=NO

chroot_local_user=YES

# ========================================
# Custom added lines
# ========================================

# Logging for fail2ban
log_ftp_protocol=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

# New settings mentioned in guide 
# https://computingforgeeks.compasv_min_port/configure-vsftpd-ftp-server-on-rocky-almalinux/

# Restrict user access to their home directory only and grant the write permissions.
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

# Passive ports
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=31000

# Allow dedicated Vsftpd users in the user_list file to access the FTP server.
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list

# Different to guide!
userlist_deny=YES

Problem
I would expect to now be able to login as root and do whatever I want.
I can login. I can navigate to any folder. I can download files.
I cannot upload files or created folders.
# Trying to create a folder /root/MyFolder in FileZilla I get the following error:
Status: Erstelle Verzeichnis '/root/MyFolder'...
Befehl: CWD /root
Antwort:    250 Directory successfully changed.
Befehl: MKD MyFolder
Antwort:    550 Create directory operation failed.

# Trying to upload a random file MyTestFile.txt into folder /root/Downloads/ using FileZilla I get the following error:
Befehl: CWD /root/Downloads
Antwort:    250 Directory successfully changed.
Befehl: TYPE A
Antwort:    200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Befehl: PASV
Antwort:    227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,77,140,117,137).
Befehl: STOR MyTestFile.txt
Antwort:    553 Could not create file.
Fehler: Kritischer Dateiübertragungsfehler

What am I missing?

As hinted by HBruijn’s comment on Server Fault, the problem was SELinux being enabled:

In RHEL and derivatives SELinux is enabled by default and that may impose and enforce restrictions regardless of how you (mis) configure your daemons

In short, this is how you can check the state and the command to run in order to disable SELinux:
// Check whether SELinux is enabled
# getenforce
Enforcing

// Disable SELinux permanently
# sudo nano /etc/selinux/config

...
SELINUX=disabled
...

// Reboot the PC after you saved the file.
# reboot

// Check again the state.
# getenforce
Disabled

